# Raspberry PI: PyBluez service (UUID) not found (sdptool+Android app)

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I tried to write a simple Bluetooth Server socket on the raspberry pi, according to the example of pybluez: https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py

I tried to connect from within an Android app.

When I run my Android app, I can't connect to the Server socket. When I Display the UUIDs seen by Android I get the following list, not containing my actual Service on the PI:

```
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/DevName﹕ RichPi
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
08-05 22:11:33.806  13510-13510/ch.erni.btlintilla D/UUID﹕ 00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

I then ran `sdptool browse` on the PI and didn't discover any devices.

I have already tried different Solutions mentioned in similar threads (DisablePlugins = pnat, Pairing Prior to starting the Service). Any help appreciated.

Below the sample code used to create the Server socket on the py.

```
# file: rfcomm-server.py
# auth: Albert Huang <albert@csail.mit.edu>
# desc: simple demonstration of a server application that uses RFCOMM sockets
#
# $Id: rfcomm-server.py 518 2007-08-10 07:20:07Z albert $

from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
#                   protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ] 
                    )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```